# JSON default Ruby library

Tags: json, ruby, rubygems

I have a bit of JSON code I'm using to make a Ruby app work. It checks out on most linters and validators (I haven't tried one where it doesn't work.)

The thing is, though, the Ruby library for it doesn't work. I continue trying it, with different ways and tries, but it just won't load right. It gives me an unexpected token error. I'm just very confused, because it works on the other validators I've tried. Is the gem broken, or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: The code being used is the JSON.parse method, after a to_json method from a file.read method. The content is being read straight from a file.

Content:

```
{
"black":{ "id":10, "title":"Black Room",
"desc":"You're in a large, black room filled with cobwebs.",
"around":[20, 30], "items":[], "npcs":[] },

"grey":{ "id":20, "title":"Grey Room",
"desc":"You're in a fine, grey room filled with nothing all.",
"around":[10, 20], "items":[], "npcs":[] },

"white":{ "id":30, "title":"White Room",
"desc":"You're in a small, white room filled with sunlight.",
"around":[10, 30], "items":[], "npcs":[] },

"null":{ "id":0, "title":"Null Room",
"desc":"You shouldn't be in here... please leave.",
"around":[10, 20, 30], "items":[], "npcs":[] }
}
```

Comment: "AM I doing something wrong?"...we don't know...we'll need to see an example of JSON that you're having trouble working with and the code you're using that isn't producing the correct results.

Comment: @SimpleLime That's the thing. It works on many, many other areas. I've tried it in linters, validators, and JS. The only place it doesn't work is the Ruby gem.

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" Please leave a CODE SAMPLE. If your question is "does Ruby parse valid JSON?" then the answer is yes. If you would like someone to tell you why YOUR Ruby code doesn't work, then post YOUR RUBY CODE.

Comment: those lines you've put is a candidate to be ruby hash. generally json strings are passed to `JSON.parse` to transform it to a hash object. you can however convert this hash to a string  - `you_hash.to_json`, then pass the outcome to `JSON.parse`. thus you'll see there will be no errors

Comment: @marmeladze I used the to_json function.

Comment: set that hash equal to a variable `x`, then `JSON.parse x.to_json` works fine.

Comment: @maxpleaner It was already set to a variable called "content" and that's how I used the to_json function

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Turns out, there were no code issues, but the problem lied within the file encoding itself. I had it encoded in UTF-8, like most of my other files, and the default on my text editor. I converted the file to ASCII and it worked fine. Thanks for the help, though.